# How to create macro in sublime text 3 with saveAs and close file command?

Tags: macros, command, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I need to change encoding of a lot of html files to UTF8 (from Windows 1252). I´m using Sublime text 3 on Windows 8. So I think creating macro will be very efficient, I need just two commands in that macro "Save with Encoding - UTF8" and "Close file". But when I´m trying to record macro these commands are not recorded. So I need to manually create json file with macro command but I don´t know how.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=8677

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure that this can be done with a macro maybe these commands are out of scope for a macro (eg a [window command](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html#window-commands) not a view command?), but I managed to make it work as a plugin…

Save the following as `$PATH_TO_SUBLIME_DATA/Packages/SaveAs-UTF8.py`

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SaveAsUtf8Command(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command("save", {"encoding": "utf-8" })
        self.window.run_command("close")
```

To trigger the command with 'Command Option Shift 8', add the following to your `Sublime Text > Preferences > Keybindings - User` file:

```
[
    { "keys": ["super+option+shift+8"], "command": "save_as_utf8"}
]
```

I've saved this as a gist if you prefer: https://gist.github.com/9505499

Comment: (tested on OSX ST3 build 3059)

Comment: Do you know why a command created this way can't be used in a macro (and isn't registered when "recording macro")? I did the same except that my class is named ``SaveInMacroCommand`` and only has ``self.window.run_command("save")`` and it works the same as regular save when bound to a key, but when used in macro as ``"command": "save_in_macro"`` I get ``Unknown macro command save_in_macro`` error, even though when executing the key shortcut, the file is saved as expected and the panel/console shows "command: save_in_macro" was executed.

Comment: Explanation to the comment above: I need to use ``save_in_macro`` inside a macro, which does a couple of other things, including executing other commands, inserting snippet and executing system command (so it doesn't make sense, even if possible, to include all that in the new command/package code).